# Javascript challenge - How to call a function such that it returns 8?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, challenge-response

Long time ago I saw a Javascript challenge, I do not remember where, but now I am trying to solve it. Until now, I do not know how to proceed.

I have this function and I have to make a call such that it returns 8:

```
function foo(a, b){
    b(function(){
        return a + a;
    });
}
```

Since `foo` does not return anything, is it possible to make the call I need? or it is just a tricky question?

Comment: depends on what you precisely mean with *"make a call such that it returns 8"*. I think the precise form of the original question is important here.

Comment: Yes. The way `foo` is defined, it never returns anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not remember the original statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "return" you mean alert or log it somewhere it is easy as:

```
foo(4, function(fn){
   console.log(fn());
});
```

Or even ignoring the input:

```
foo('bar', function(){
   console.log(8);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept you answer since given the comments it is not possible to actually return something.

Comment: Although the second example is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
var r = foo(foo(0, function(){ foo = function(){ return 8 } }));
```

This gives to `r` the returned value which is `8`.

Comment: When I execute your code chrome says: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"